# PCL cube detection

Tags: point-cloud-library

I want to use PCL(point cloud library) to implement cube or rectangle detection for any size in a scene.

Can anyone give me some direction?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php) PCL tutorial or, in general, at all the techniques implemented in the `pcl::recognition` module.

On the PCL users mailing list archive ([here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Detecting-quot-simple-quot-objects-in-a-point-cloud-td3468335.html)), there is an older but yet useful discussion about simple object recognition. For simple objects, as in your case, you may consider using Sample Consensus for segmenting the model inside your scene point cloud.